# How to Retain Integer in MySQL Query on IF() Clause

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I have a problem with an IF() clause on my query statement. I am simply moving an integer to another column that I dynamically create in my query statement but the integer loses its attribute classification and MySQL treats it as a string.

```
mysql_query('
    SELECT id, statusDate, displayName, earnings,
        IF(statusDate <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00", earnings, "0") as earnings1
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY statusDate, earnings1 DESC, displayName
');
```

I have some `earnings` in the table such as 10, 50, 200, etc.

Since I am doing a descending order by, I am expecting:
200
50
10

But what I am getting is: 10, 200, 50

Any idea on how I can retain `earnings` as an integer, when moving to `earnings1`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both arguments in the `IF` function are number you shouldn't get this problem. So if `earnings` is numeric, try this for your `earnings1` value:

```
IF(status <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00", earnings, 0) as earnings1

                                              ^ note no more quotes
```

Comment: awesome @EdGibbs -- that did it!

Comment: I started out without the quotes. But one of MySQL errors caused me to think the 0 was cause the query to fail so I wrapped it on quotes. Anyway, I got it working now...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This work for you?

```
SELECT id, statusDate, displayName, earnings,
    (CAST( IF(statusDate <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00", earnings, 0) AS SIGNED)) as earnings1
```

Comment: I'l try it and post back @CaptainSkyhawk. Thanks.

Comment: This may or may not work depending on where it's doing its sorting/ordering. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your help @CaptainSkyhawk but I got it to work on an answer from EdGibbs

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the CASE statement and more importantly, remove the quotes " from the 0 to preserve an int datatype.

```
SELECT id, statusDate, displayName, earnings,
    CASE WHEN statusDate <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
    THEN earnings
    ELSE  0 
    END as earnings1
FROM my_table
ORDER BY statusDate, earnings1 DESC, displayName
```